# Animation not animated in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am designing a simulation viewer in which points are animated using FuncAnimation in matplotlib.

This is what I have so far (the VX, VY, M, t_lim will be used later). It only produces a blank plot and nothing moves.

I've copied some of it from the first example from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

This is really simple (literally two points coming together in one timestep), why doesn't this work?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

class visualisation(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y, VX, VY, M, t_lim=None):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.VX = VX
        self.VY = VY
        self.M = M
        self.t_lim = t_lim

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        addx = (X.max() - X.min()) * 0.05
        addy = (Y.max() - Y.min()) * 0.05
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(X.min()-addx, X.max()+addx), ylim=(Y.min()-addy, Y.max()+addy))
        self.points, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'b.', ms=10)

    def init(self):
        self.points.set_data([], [])
        return self.points,

    def animator(self, i):
        print self.X[:,i]
        self.points.set_data(self.X[:,i], self.Y[:,i])
        return self.points,

    def animate(self):
        return animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animator, init_func=self.init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)


M_sun = 2.99e30
N = 1000

ms = np.array([1., 1.]) * M_sun

#initial conditions
xs = np.zeros([len(ms), N]) #[n, t]
xs[:, 0] = [0, 1]

ys = np.zeros([len(ms), N]) #[n, t]
ys[:, 0] = [0, 1]

vxs, vys = (np.zeros_like(xs))*2

visual = visualisation(xs, ys, vxs, vys, ms)
visual.animate()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the `FuncAnimation` object that you create in `animate(self)`. Otherwise it is garbage collected before `plt.show()` is called:

```
amin = visual.animate()
```

or:

```
def animate(self):
    self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animator, 
            init_func=self.init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```